# updating field in a record in a not primary entity using plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I'm facing a problem in doing a plugin for the Dynamics CRM 365.
I have 2 entities, Account and website, account entity have a text field called website and a subgrid related to website entity.
My task is to do a plugin that runs on post-create of a new  website entity from the subgrid in the account form. The plugin should copy a text field from the new created website record to the website text field in the account form.

I register the plugin for website entity as a primary entity,
the code reads the guid of the account and the needed filed in the new created website, my problem is that I cannot update the website field in account.

My code:

```
var AccountId = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_accountid");
var WebsiteDomain = entity.Attributes["new_url"].ToString();
   if (WebsiteDomain != null && WebsiteDomain != "" && AccountId != null && AccountId.Id!=null)
   {                    
      try
       {
          Entity obj = new Entity("account", new 
          Guid(AccountId.Id.ToString()));
          obj["websiteurl"] = WebsiteDomain;
          service.Update(obj);  
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {                  
          throw;
       }
   }
```

The error when reaching the update statement:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHRlv.png)

Comment: May be websiteurl is not the right schema name. It should start like new_ or any other prefix.. verify it..

Comment: no,, the schema name for this field is websiteurl

Comment: In this code, key from dictionary can be only 3. new_url new_accountid or websiteurl. It can be identified by debugging.. you know what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked it.

```
var WebsiteDomain = entity.Attributes["new_url"].ToString();
```

In this above line, you are assuming `new_url` key will be always there & converting `.ToString()`. This is highly error prone, as key may be wrong or it may be null.

Without null check or verifying `Attributes.Contains` don’t utilize the attribute key like this.

Safely you can use `GetAttributeValue` atleast. Read [Tips](https://crmtipsbyprm.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-dynamic-crm/)

Comment: Another approach would be to use a POST image so that `new_url` will always be present in the attribute bag